# UriMatcher won't match uri

Tags: android, uri

I'm trying to make custom suggestion to search dialog. I'm using a urimatcher to match uri. But it dont work. I always get the exception " java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Uri: content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/search_suggest_query/?limit=50". Please explain this to me. What can I do to resolve this?

```
private static final UriMatcher sURIMatcher = makeUriMatcher();
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection,
        String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    // Use UriMatcher, to find out what type of request received. Next, form
    // the corresponding query to the database
    switch (sURIMatcher.match(uri)) {
    case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
        if (selectionArgs == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
        }
        return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0]);
    case SEARCH_TESTS:
        if (selectionArgs == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
        }
        return search(selectionArgs[0]);
    case GET_TEST:
        return getRecord(uri);
    default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Uri: " + uri);
    }
```

makeUrimatcher

```
private static UriMatcher makeUriMatcher() {

    UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    // For the record
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "tests", SEARCH_TESTS);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "tests/#", GET_TEST);
    // For suggestions table
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY,
            SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*",
            SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    return matcher;
}
```

logcat

```
11-30 14:16:27.295: I/ActivityThread(1638): Publishing provider com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider: com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider
11-30 14:16:35.424: D/com.simple.search.com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider(1638): Unknown Uri: content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/search_suggest_query/?limit=50
11-30 14:16:35.424: E/DatabaseUtils(1638): Writing exception to parcel
11-30 14:16:35.424: E/DatabaseUtils(1638): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown Uri: content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/search_suggest_query/?limit=50
11-30 14:16:35.424: E/DatabaseUtils(1638):  at com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider.query(SuggestionProvider.java:122)
11-30 14:16:35.424: E/DatabaseUtils(1638):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkQuery(ContentProvider.java:117)
11-30 14:16:35.424: E/DatabaseUtils(1638):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:98)
11-30 14:16:35.424: E/DatabaseUtils(1638):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:287)
11-30 14:16:35.424: E/DatabaseUtils(1638):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

searchable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" 
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:searchSuggestAuthority="com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider"
    android:searchSuggestIntentAction="android.intent.action.VIEW"
    android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/tests"
    />
```

Manifest

```
....
....
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SimpleSearch" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
                <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                   android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
        </activity>
....
....
```

Comment: uri should be `content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/search_suggest_query?limit=50` not `content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/search_suggest_query/?limit=50`

Comment: @selvin thanks man. But still not working.

Comment: same error ? ... how you do this query ? from your code or QSB?(for QSB  code looks good) add L.d("TAG", uri.toString())  ... how exaclly sURIMatcher is created ... maybe it's not this mather as you create by makeUriMatcher ... i used to make mather final static and build it in static{ ... } "constructor"

Comment: @selvin Added urimatcher. Same error. I do query from qsb. Can you give an example matcher final static please?

Comment: full logcat log ... + searchable.xml + search activity definition from AndroidManifest.xml ... `class provider { private final static UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH); static { matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY,
            SEARCH_SUGGEST); } /*... rest of the provider class class */}`

Comment: @selvin added those to question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To avoid discussion i'll change this answer if you provide more information...

but for now ...

you have `android:searchSuggestIntentData="content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/tests"` in xml

so you have to change

```
private static UriMatcher makeUriMatcher() {

    UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    // For the record
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "tests", SEARCH_TESTS);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "tests/#", GET_TEST);
    // For suggestions table
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "tests/" + SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY,
            SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    matcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "tests/" + SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY + "/*",
            SEARCH_SUGGEST);
    return matcher;
}
```

if you dont see differences i added "tests/"

so now it will match `content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/tests/search_suggest_query?limit=50` which is exactly what QSB will send ...

anyway you can/should add limit to your query

```
case SEARCH_SUGGEST:
    if (selectionArgs == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "selectionArgs must be provided for the Uri: " + uri);
    }
    final String limit = uri.getQueryParameter(SearchManager.SUGGEST_PARAMETER_LIMIT);
    return getSuggestions(selectionArgs[0], limit);
```

and then in getSuggestions

```
helper.getReadableDatabase().query(table, projection,
                    selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder, limit);
```

**EDIT**:

`AUTHORITY + "tests/" + SearchManager.SUGGEST_URI_PATH_QUERY` should be the same as `android:searchSuggestIntentData` !!!

**EDIT2:** from doc http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/adding-custom-suggestions.html

> selection The value provided in the android:searchSuggestSelection
>   attribute of your searchable configuration file, or null if you have
>   not declared the android:searchSuggestSelection attribute. More about
>   using this to get the query below. selectionArgs Contains the search
>   query as the first (and only) element of the array if you have
>   declared the android:searchSuggestSelection attribute in your
>   searchable configuration. If you have not declared
>   android:searchSuggestSelection, then this parameter is null. More
>   about using this to get the query below.

add `android:searchSuggestSelection=" ? "`

Comment: added code like you said. But still throwing the same exception. I skipped limit because i haven't implemented it in getSuggestions() :(

Comment: one more doubt, the uri returned by qsm is still content://com.simple.search.SuggestionProvider/search_suggest_query?. no tests/ why?